Evaluate the infinite summation and find $L$

Evaluate
$$
L=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^r\left(1 + 2^{1/2^{\LARGE r}}\right)}
$$
At first glance, I thought the limit could be solved by converting it to a Reimman Sum. But I don't see how that can be done (if possible) because we cannot get the $r/n$ expression in this sum.

Next, I thought that this could be an expansion of an expression. But I don't know any expression whose expansion looks like this.
Do you have any ideas on how to approach this?$
Any help is greatly appreciated.

I think the value is $\frac{1}{\ln(2)}-1$, so that might imply differentiation and integration could come into play, but I'm struggling to get a proper proof.

@DarmaniV you're right...the answer is indeed what you told

$$L=\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^r}\frac{1}{1+2^{\frac{1}{2^r}}}\\
=\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^r}\left(\frac{1}{1+2^{\frac{1}{2^r}}}+\frac{1}{1-2^{\frac{1}{2^r}}}-\frac{1}{1-2^{\frac{1}{2^r}}}\right)\\
=\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^r}\left(\frac{2}{1-2^{2\frac{1}{2^r}}}-\frac{1}{1-2^{\frac{1}{2^r}}}\right)\\
=\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2^{r-1}}\frac{1}{1-2^{\frac{1}{2^{r-1}}}}-\frac{1}{2^r}\frac{1}{1-2^{\frac{1}{2^r}}}\right)$$
Observe the telescoping series
$$\sum\limits_{r=1}^{\infty}(a_{r-1}-a_{r})=\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\sum\limits_{r=1}^{N}(a_{r-1}-a_{r})=\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}a_{0}-a_{N}$$
$$a_{0}=\frac{1}{2^{0}}\frac{1}{1-2^{\frac{1}2^{0}}}=\frac{1}{1-2}=-1$$
$$\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}a_{N}=\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\frac{2^{-N}}{1-2^{2^{-N}}}$$
This is $\frac{0}{0}$, so apply L'Hôpital's rule.
$$\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}a_N=\frac{(2^{-N})'}{-2^{2^{-N}}\ln(2)(2^{-N})'}=\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\frac{1}{-2^{2^{-N}}\ln(2)}=\frac{1}{-\ln(2)}$$
Finally we get
$$L=a_{0}-\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}a_N=-1-\frac{1}{-\ln(2)}=\frac{1}{\ln(2)}-1$$
